# Copy files in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an installer-like application. Here is what its supposed to do: create a directory in C: and name it batch. Then copy the files from the folder and move it to the C:\batch directory. But the copying of files doesn't work.

How am I supposed to put the exact directory in here if that exact directory does not apply to all? What do I do with it? If the file that is to be copied is from: `E:\Documents and Settings\Rew\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\batch\batch`

I want it to be universal. So that wherever the file maybe it could always copy it regardless of where it is located.

Somehow the creating of a directory work.

```
Dim FileToCopy As String
Dim NewCopy As String
Try
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Batch")

    FileToCopy = "\batch\batch\ipconfigrenew.bat"
    FileToCopy = "\batch\batch\ipconfigrelease.bat"
    FileToCopy = "\batch\batch\ipconfigflushdns.bat"
    NewCopy = "C:\Batch"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
        MsgBox("File Copied")
    End If
Catch
End Try
MsgBox("Done")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the only value in FileToCopy by the time you do the copy is the last one. I'm having trouble parsing the question to figure out what you need, but I would first do this:

```
    Dim FileToCopy(3) As String
    FileToCopy(0) = "\batch\batch\ipconfigrenew.bat"
    FileToCopy(1) = "\batch\batch\ipconfigrelease.bat"
    FileToCopy(2) = "\batch\batch\ipconfigflushdns.bat"
    Dim NewCopy As String = "C:\Batch"
    Dim s As String
    For Each s In FileToCopy
        If System.IO.File.Exists(s) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(s, NewCopy)
            MsgBox("File Copied")
        End If
    Next
```

Next, I would decide if I needed to write this in a more generic way.