# How to copy one file to another in vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if the file exist or not. If file not exists then I need to copy one file to another

I tired like this

Dim roming As String
            roming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

If Not File.Exists(roming & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString & CONFIG_FILE) Then

I need to copy the default file to roming path file

default file is :  My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & CONFIG-FILE

Comment: Have you ever considered a situation when a file would exist at the time you check for its existence, but will get deleted by the time you execute your dependent action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is the code :

```
Dim roming As String
roming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
If Not File.Exists(roming & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString & CONFIG_FILE) Then
IO.File.Copy(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & CONFIG-FILE , roming & "\" & Environment.UserName.ToString & CONFIG_FILE)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but here is a simple example :

```
Dim OriginalFilePath As String = "Put here you file path"
Dim NewFilePath As String = "Put here you new file, that you want to copy into it"
' Checks if the original file exists in the file system of the computer.
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(OriginalFilePath) = True Then
     ' Creates a new file, and copy all the content of the original file, into it
     System.IO.File.Copy(OriginalFilePath, NewFilePath)
End If
```

For further information, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390813/copy-files-in-vb-net?rq=1).